# Firefox doesn't understand svg on remote server

Tags: apache, firefox, svg

I've got a curious problem where FireFox (and IE9, I think) can display a local html file which embeds an svg, but it can't display exactly the same file when it's on a remote server. Any ideas much appreciated.

The setup is that I have a test directory which contains index.html, an svg file, and a js file. When I point any browser at index.html it correctly displays the embedded svg. However, when when I upload this test directory to a remote server, then:

1 - Opera, Safari, and Chrome correctly display the svg

2 - FireFox complains that it needs a plugin for the svg

3 - IE9 displays nothing.

Something is different about the remote setup, but I have no idea what. My suspicion is that this is an interaction of some sort with Apache (when I view index.html locally I'm not using Apache, of course - the browser is directly viewing the file).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you link to it so i can inspect what the server is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the remote server sends the appropriate MIME type "image/svg+xml".

Comment: Thanks - added that to my Apache config and it worked. Curious that Chrome/Opera/Safari don't actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

I run to this issue aswell on my remote server.

Adding this to .htaccess file solved my problem.

```
    AddType image/svg+xml svg
    AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

For more information see [SVG MIME TYPE](http://planetsvg.com/tools/mime.php)